# Why converting datetime to string gets me the error : ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: c#, oracle, datareader

I have the following column :

```
CheckingTime
------------
1 7/5/2011
2 
3 
4 5/8/2012
```

(the colomn format is date.)
I'm using a datareader to read all colomns and rows in DB1 and insert them into DB 2 as follow :

```
while (dr.Read())
{
string finalratingdate = ((dr[19] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToString(dr[19]) : "");
}
```

So when inserting it's supposed to check if there's a DBNull, if not, insert the value, if yes insert "", but the thing is I get the following error :

System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

I only get this error with datetimes variable. All other variables i'm able to convert them to string and insert them.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe the exception is indicating that your column in the database is of type `Date` and it can't accommodate empty string. Instead of Empty String in your statement, you should initialize your variable with `null`, that will enable you to set null value in `Date` column. So your statement would be:

```
string finalratingdate = ((dr[19] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToString(dr[19]) : null);
```

I am not really sure why are you converting a `DateTime` field to string for database, you should use Parameterized query and add the `DataTime` object as parameter instead of converting it to string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried what you suggested and i'm still receiving the same error : System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

I'm converting a datime to string because i was having issues with DBNulls in decimal colomns and converting the values to string corrected the issue. Now I tried the same with datetime colomns but with no success